# Visualize boost graph topology after layout algorithm is performed

Tags: boost, layout, boost-graph, topology

I am using `fruchterman_reingold_force_directed_layout` algorithm on my graph
to get a cluster free layout. Below is code for my vertices and edge

```
using RectTopology = boost::rectangle_topology<>;
using point = RectTopology::point_type;

class MyVertex{
public:
    MyVertex(){ myObject = NULL; }
    Mybject* myObject;
    point position;
    std::string name;
};

class MyEdge{
public:
    MyEdge(){ myLine = NULL; }
    MyLine* myLine;
    double weight;
};

//Boost graph defination
using graphT = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, MyVertex, MyEdge>;
using vertexT = boost::graph_traits<graphT>::vertex_descriptor; //Define Vertex
using vertexIt = boost::graph_traits<graphT>::vertex_iterator; //Vertex Iterator
using edgeT = boost::graph_traits<graphT>::edge_descriptor; //Define Edge
using edgeIt = boost::graph_traits<graphT>::edge_iterator; //Edge Iterator


forcedDirLay(){
    boost::minstd_rand gen;
    RectTopology rect_top(gen, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    boost::random_graph_layout(myGraph, boost::get(&SLDVertex::position, myGraph), rect_top);
    boost::fruchterman_reingold_force_directed_layout(myGraph, boost::get(&SLDVertex::position, myGraph), rect_top);
}
```

Imagine now I have a graph and perform my layout algorithm which all works fine
and I have position info for every vertices.

How can I visualize each vertex where they end up after layout algorithm
finished ? Is there a way to get position info to Dot file and I can visualize
Dot file ?

I have a function to convert my graph to dot file but don't know how
to get position info to dot
file. Thanks in advance.

```
GraphToDotFile(){
    std::ofstream dot(".\\graph.dot");
    boost::write_graphviz(dot, myGraph, 
        boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(&MyVertex::name, myGraph)));
    dot.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic properties to add graphviz attributes, see the example:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/graph/example/graphviz.cpp

The attributes that specify the position in graphviz are [here](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:pos):

[image]

> Position of node, or spline control points.
>
> For nodes, the position indicates the center of the node. On output,
> the coordinates are in points.
>
> In `neato` and `fdp`, pos can be used to set the initial position of a
> node. By default, the coordinates are assumed to be in inches.
> However, the `-s` command line flag can be used to specify different
> units. As the output coordinates are in points, feeding the output of
> a graph laid out by a Graphviz program into `neato` or `fdp` will almost
> always require the `-s` flag.
>
> When the `-n` command line flag is used with `neato`, it is assumed the
> positions have been set by one of the layout programs, and are
> therefore in points. Thus, `neato -n` can accept input correctly without
> requiring a `-s` flag and, in fact, ignores any such flag.
>
> ***Valid for: Edges, Nodes.***

Answer (score 1):

The **neato -n** trick works like a champ.
Adding a bit to the above,
**yourProg** produces **graph.dot**; then
**neato -n -Tpng graph.dot >graph.png**
You may have to fiddle with **yourProg** to make sure that **graph.dot** has all the required attributes, units are correct, etc.  You can produce a tiny example by hand, then
**dot -Tdot tiny.gv >tiny.dot**
and compare the two **.dot** files